# Exploring a ASP.NET website's code

Tags: asp.net

I have been set a new project at work and have been given the code beforehand to give it a good look. Since time is limited, can anyone please give me the best way to get a good feel of the project. What are the things I should be looking for within the code?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of application is it? What .net version? Generally, more details

Comment: I'd start by reading the functional spec for the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first I'd get the app running and get a sense of the functionality (the business functionality) of the application. If you're not familiar with the business functionality, keep notes on your questions.

Next examine the code. things like:
1. Database access methodology (ASP.NET Core, Linq2SQL, EF, NHibernate etc.)
2. Take a look at the database and the data model
3. Examine the areas you're not comfortable with in regards the ASP.NET/C# etc.

Keep a note of questions you have through this phase. If they want you to hit the ground running, you'll need your questions answered. Asking the right (intelligent) questions shows you've spent time examining the code (as they would expect)

Answer (score 2):

Set a breakpoint at the `page_load` or `init` event handler of a page of interest and step through the code (<kbd>F11</kbd>) to see where it goes and what it does.